# Android disable notifications shade and soft buttons swipe

Tags: android, notifications

I'm making an slideshow app for device running Android. I want to disable notification shade and soft buttons swipe to prevent customers from accessing OS. I know that i can use TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY flag, but it disables touch events, so this is not a solution. Is there are way to achieve what i want? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated devices that should "disable notifications shade and soft buttons" aka kiosk mode, should use screen pinning or task locking. For information about implementation of kiosk mode read  [Dedicated devices overview](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) and [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager).